# How to display nodejs raw Buffer data as Hex string

Tags: node.js, buffer

The following code uses SerialPort module to listen to data from a bluetooth connection.

I am expecting to see a stream of data in Hexadecimal format printed in console. But the console just shows some weird simbols. I want to know how can I decode and display the data in console.

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort", {
  parser: SP.parsers.raw
}, false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]

serialPort.open(function () {
 console.log('open');
 serialPort.on('data', function(data) {
   var buff = new Buffer(data, 'utf8'); //no sure about this
  console.log('data received: ' + buff.toString());
 });  
});
```

Comment: data is already a buffer, no need to convert. Then: data.toString('hex');

Answer (score 288, accepted):

This code will show the data buffer as a hex string:

```
buff.toString('hex');
```

Comment: do u know how to do the reverse?

Comment: bubakazouba:  new Buffer( buf.toString('hex'), 'hex' );

Comment: [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

So now it should be `Buffer.from( buf.toString('hex'),'hex');`

Comment: It returns for me `[object ArrayBuffer]`? what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Top answer is the simplest way to do it.

An alternative method:

```
data = Buffer.from([0x62, 0x75, 0x66, 0x66, 0x65, 0x72]);

Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(data),
               x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2))
        .join('').match(/[a-fA-F0-9]{2}/g).reverse().join('');
```

Comment: This answer was actually useful for me, because I have to join it with '-' for it to interop with C#. Upvoted.