# Convert byte array to Hex string using Mongoose Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a byte array field in mongodb. while reading i have to show the binary data as hex string.

I am using express js, mongoose , node js to read data from mongodb.

In java to convert hex string to byte array we have:

**byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);**

And byte array to hex string we have

**DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);**

I want to similar function which does the same job in node js.

also please guide me how to define schema to achieve in mongoose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display nodejs raw Buffer data as Hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879880/how-to-display-nodejs-raw-buffer-data-as-hex-string)

Answer (score 0):

In node you can use Buffer:

```
var a = Buffer.from([0x06, 0x75, 0x66, 0x66, 0x65, 0x72]).toString("hex"); // '067566666572'

// reverse operation
var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(new Buffer.from(a, "hex"), 0); // [ 6, 117, 102, 102, 101, 114 ]
```