# Converting a buffer to a hex string

Tags: node.js, hex, buffer

I want to convert a node JS buffer to a hex string. Obviously, I googled this first, but none of the proposed solutions work.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879880/how-to-display-nodejs-raw-buffer-data-as-hex-string) a comment below the accepted answer says you should do it like this:

```
let signature4 = Buffer.from(signature3.r, 'hex') + Buffer.from(signature3.s, 'hex') + Buffer.from(signature3.v, 'hex');
```

But this yields:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "value" argument must not be of type number. Received type number
```

If I go for the actual answer which tells me to do it like this:

```
let signature4 = signature3.r.toString('hex') + signature3.s.toString('hex') + signature3.v.toString('hex');
```

I get this error:

```
 RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36
```

If I follow the advice given in the error message and enter 16 as a number like so:

```
let signature4 = signature3.r.toString(16) + signature3.s.toString(16) + signature3.v.toString(16);
```

I get this error message:

```
 TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: 16
```

If I instead pass 16 as a string:

```
let signature4 = signature3.r.toString('16') + signature3.s.toString('16') + signature3.v.toString('16');
```

I get the same error message:

```
 TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: 16
```

So what's the current way of doing it?

I use Node v10.18.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me... is your object actually an Node.js buffer?

```
Buffer.from([255,254,0,1]).toString("hex") // ffee0001
```

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid now. Shouldn't have written all of that in one line. The `r` and `s` values are buffers but `v` is not. `v` is a number. So I need to pass `'hex'` to `toString()` of `r` and `s` but I need to pass `16` to `toString` of `v`.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)